# Difference of cv::filter2D and self-contained convolution on Gabor filter

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Due to some reason, I have to write the filter function myself. The following is my convolution function.

```
void Convolve (cv::Mat& f, cv::Mat& w, cv::Mat& output)
{
  output = f.clone();

  int height = f.rows;
  int width = f.cols;
  int a = (w.rows - 1) / 2;
  int b = (w.cols- 1) / 2;

  cv::Mat f2 = f.clone();

  for (int x = a; x < height - a; ++x)
  {
    for (int y = b; y < width - b; ++y)
    {
      float sum = 0.0;
      for (int s = -a; s <= a; ++s)
      { 
        for (int t = -b; t <= b; ++t)
        {
          sum += w.at<float>(s+a, t+b) * f2.at<float>(x+s, y+t);
        }
      }
      output.at<float>(x, y) = sum;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I compare using this function and cv::filter2D function, and discover they are different after filtering. The filtered image is almost the same when theta and psi are zero but not others.

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat in = cv::imread("something.jpg", 0);
    cv::Mat dest, dest1;
    cv::Mat src_f;
    in.convertTo(src_f, CV_32F);

    int kernel_size = 31;
    double sig = 1.0, th = 0.2, lm = 1.0, gm = 0.02, ps = 0.0;

    cv::Mat kernel =    cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);

    cv::filter2D(src_f, dest1, CV_32F, kernel);
    Convolve(src_f, kernel, dest);

    cv::Mat viz;
    dest.convertTo(viz, CV_8U, 1.0/255.0);
    cv::Mat viz1;
    dest1.convertTo(viz1, CV_8U, 1.0/255.0); 
    imshow("my dest", viz);
    imshow("k dest", viz1);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Any suggestion for the self-contained convolution ? The zero padding part is ignored.

Comment: "Due to some reason" :D

Answer (score 0):

You access the kernel in your convolution implementations as a matrix of floats, but it is composed of doubles (`ksize` is set to `CV_64F` by default, according to the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaborkernel)). It looks like OpenCV is smart enough to detect it and perform the conversion/correct memory access itself during convolution of matrices with different element types, that's why it produces correct results.

In order to fix your snippet I added a line

```
kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_32F);
```

This produces a visually equivalent result (up to padding).

Another option would be to explicitly set the `ktype` to `CV_32F`.

Also, when working with big kernels (~11x11 and larger) OpenCV's `filter2D` implementation performs the convolution using the DFT-based algorithm (in frequency domain), so you may get slightly different results and timings.